# Пользовательский Placemark

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_layout

По примеру сделал анимированный Placemark. У меня на странице их несколько и получается у каждого свой внутренний стейт, хочется чтобы был активным только 1 Placemark. Попытался работать через state проставляя кастомное свойство isActive свойствами, но к сожалению видимо placemark его понимает. Каким образом можно добиться поведения когда активна только одна метка?

Comment: А что подразумевается под активной меткой? Метка на которую был совершен клик?

Comment: @Shadowalker именно